# What kind of equation is this, $(z+1) (x^2+y^2) = 2ax+2by$ where $z=f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm stuck up with the equation $(z+1) (x^2+y^2) = 2ax+2by$, where $z=f(x,y)$.
What kind of equation is this?

When googled, it leads to calculus, multivariable equations,...

Is there any concept of tri-variable quadratic equations?

Can anyone suggest some books (elementary ones as I had done maths until higher secondary level only)?

Answer (score 1):

The equation allows you to define $z$ as a function of $x,y$ (and $a,b$). We say that $z=f(x,y)$ is **implicitly defined** in terms of $x,y,a,b$ by the given equation.

Since the equation is polynomial, we say that $z=f(x,y)$ is an **algebraic function**.

But in this particular example we can solve for $z$ and get $z=\frac{2ax+2by}{x^2+y^2}-1$.
So, we see that $z=f(x,y)$ is a **rational function**, a quotient of polynomials.